# Move sibling node into current node with XSL template

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL Templates and am attempting what I thought would be a simple transformation, but I am not getting very far.  I want to transform this XML:

```
<Books>
    <Name>
        <p>Romeo and Juliet</p>
    </Name>
    <Text>
        <p>Two houses...</p>
    </Text>
    <Name>
        <p>Hamlet</p>
    </Name>
    <Text>
        <p>Who's there...</p>
    </Text>
</Books>
```

to this:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>Romeo and Juliet</Title>
        <Content>
            <p>Two houses...</p>
        </Content>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>Hamlet</Title>
        <Content>
            <p>Who's there...</p>
        </Content>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Note the following changes:

1. Group the `Name` element and its proceeding `Text` element into a `Book` element and rename them to `Title` and `Content`.
2. Strip the `p` tag from the `Name`, but not from the `Text`.

Here is my latest sorry attempt, which is not working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <Book>
            <Title>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </Title>
            <Content>
                <xsl:copy select="following-sibling::Text[1]"/>
            </Content>
        </Book>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="gettitle" match="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Will there always be exactly one `Text` following each `Name`? 2. Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Yes, there will always be exactly one `Text` following each `Name`.  No, I am not limited to XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they always come in pairs, why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Name">
            <Book>
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
                </Title>
                <Content>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Text[1]/p"/>
                </Content>
            </Book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In **XSLT 2.0** you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Name">
            <Book>
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
                </Title>
                <Content>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::Text]/p"/>
                </Content>
            </Book>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would work with any number of `Text` elements following a `Name`, creating a `p` element in `Content` for each one.

Comment: Thanks so much! This answers my question. One followup question I have, which should maybe be a separate question is: how can I then apply other templates to what is now moved to the `Title` element?  For example, say I have various formatting rules defined by match templates, for everything that is in `Name` and is now in `Title`.  I cannot match those templates simply on `Name`, because then that content would appear out of place, i.e. not within the `Title` tag.  But I also can't call those templates on the `Title` element, because the content of `Title` only exists AFTER the transformation

Comment: The current example is not convenient for this, but if you were to change `<xsl:value-of select="p"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>` and have a template matching `p`, then this template would be applied "to what is now moved to the `Title` element". But since there is only one such element, it is hard to see what advantage would be gained by breaking the code off to a separate template.

Comment: Indeed, my example doesn't fit my followup question.  I realize from that question and your answer that I do not have a grasp on what templates get executed when.   I found [a  great article called 'How XSLT Works'](https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/) that has helped me further. That you so much for your help!